# Skip Tachanun on the Sunday of Purim Meshulash?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, tachanun, shushan-purim

In a situation when Shushan Purim falls out on Shabbat, walled cities (which can't celebrate Purim on Shabbat) read the Megillah and give Matanot Le’Evyonim on Friday, while on Sunday they have their Purim Seudah and give Mishloach Manot.

Is Tachanun omitted on that Sunday 16 Adar even though it's not really a holiday itself? Does it matter if one is in a walled city and performing specifical commands or not?

Comment: During the period of the rishonim (with 99.9% of Jews lived outside walled cities) ttbomk no one mentions Sunday 16 Adar as a skip tachanun day. Make of that what you will.

Comment: @DoubleAA I remember a very haredi Rav telling me he doesn't say *tachanun* on Yom Haatzmaut because "how can I saw *tachanun* when so many of my brothers celebrate?" - I wonder if this has weigh in Halacha and would change the answer, now that a significant number of Jews live in Jerusalem and other walled cities

Comment: @mbloch in the days of the geonim they said tachanun on purim itself. So I can't bring proof from back when more Jews did live in walled cities, but I think it's clear you're grasping at straws here. It's clearly not a holiday, just some people have a left over chiyuv seudah no different from if they'd had a pidyon haben. We should all merit to be as zealous about most mitzvos the way some people are about coming up with excuses to skip important prayers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R. YM Tucazinsky writes in [Ir Hakodesh Vehamikdash vol. III ch. 26 p. 355](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14626&st=&pgnum=359) that those in Jerusalem recite neither *tachanun* nor *lamnatzeiach* on Sunday 16 Adar.

R. S. Deblitzky in [Purim Meshulash, ch. 7 p. 132](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1584620434100&pagenum=132&book=15259) writes that those outside of a walled city do recite *tachanun* and *lamnatzeiach* on Sunday 16 Adar, but notes that one who is accustomed not to do so has a valid custom.

Similarly, Luach Eretz Yisrael (note 178) writes that the rule is that one does recite *tachanun* in a non-walled city, but that many are accustomed not to.

However, Ishei Yisrael 25:17 fn. 59 quotes from the work Zeh HaShulchan that it would appear that one should not say *tachanun*, even in a non-walled city.

Comment: The same logic applies to Sunday the second of the month, since the same gemara that says to push seudat Purim to Sunday says the same about seudat Rosh Chodesh